# 'Debug Assertion Failed' Error when cleaning memory using 'delete' operator

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++

I have tried everything, but the code doesn't work and I can't understand why.

I have two classes. 
This one is base class:

```
class Vegetables
{
    private:
        char *nameStr;
        char *countrySrc;
        int seasonRd;
    public:
        Vegetables()
        {
            cout << "Default constructor for Vegetables" << endl;
            nameStr = new char[20];
            nameStr = "Unknown";
            countrySrc = new char[20];
            countrySrc = "Unknown";
            seasonRd = -1;
        }

        virtual ~Vegetables()
        {
            delete[]nameStr; //Here happens the error (_crtisvalidheappointer(block))
            delete[]countrySrc;
            cout << "Destructor for Vegetables" << endl;
        }
};
```

It has inherited class 'Inherited Unit':

```
class InhUnit : public Vegetables
{
    private:
        Delivery delivery_;
        Vegetables vegetables;
        int quantity;
        int price;
        int delivPrice;

    public:
        InhUnit() :Vegetables(),delivery_(OwnCosts), vegetables(), quantity(-1), price(-1), delivPrice(-1)
        {
            cout << "Default constructor for Inherited Unit" << endl;
        }

        ~InhUnit()
        {
            cout << "Destructor for Inherited Unit" << endl;
        }
};
```

What may be the reason for this error to pop up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you copy strings, use `strcpy` instead

```
    Vegetables()
    {
        cout << "Default constructor for Vegetables" << endl;
        nameStr = new char[20];
        strcpy(nameStr, "Unknown");
        countrySrc = new char[20];
        strcpy(countrySrc, "Unknown");
        seasonRd = -1;
    }
```

What you were doing is allocating some memory and assigning it to a pointer. Then on the next line you were assigning the pointer to point at a string, instead of copying the string to the memory you had allocated.

When you called `delete[]` because the pointer was not pointing at memory you had allocated you got an error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use string classes like std::string instead to avoid such pointer issues.

Answer (score 0):

Correcting the code

```
class Vegetables {
private:
    std::string nameStr;    // Use std::string instead of C-style string
    std::string countrySrc;
    int         seasonRd;

public:
    // Use constructor initialization list
    Vegetables() : nameStr("Unknown"), countrySrc("Unknown"), seasonRd(-1) {
        cout << "Default constructor for Vegetables" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~Vegetables() {
        cout << "Destructor for Vegetables" << endl;
    }
};
```